# Join Field does not work properly I end up getting Null

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have the ports shapefile downloaded from here. the 2009 version.
https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/transport-networks

I need to select and export only the ports that are inactive. In the shapefile, the points layer does not have an attribute describing the inactivity but there is another layer "PORTS_AT_2009" that does have this information on the REMK column.
Now the 2 different layers both have PORTS_ID in common and I want to take the REMK column from PORTS_AT_2009 to PORTS_PT (the points layer).

Ultimately ro reach my goal to select by attribute using the remk layer on the points.

But when I check the layer types, they are the same, as you can see in the screenshot. They ar eboth QString

[image]

Can you please help me with this?

It should be such an easy action but I repeteadly get the column as NULL since 2 days. Hope to be able to find a solution here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded the data from your link, and tested it on QGIS 3.28.11; I have encountered no errors. My suggestions are:

1. Please note, that the file `PORT_AT_2009` has 2201 records, 1826 of which have NULL value in the `REMK` field. It is quite possible that you see NULLs in the join because the ports you are interested in never had data in `REMK` in the first place. You can click on the field name in the attribute table window to order features by field value, use this to sort NULLs last so that you see which features have data.
2. If you use the Processing algorithm `Join attributes by field value`, then check your settings to match with the following screenshot:
   [image]
3. If you use Joins option in the Layer Properties window, then make sure that you have the options for `PORTS_PT_2009` open. Then match your settings with the following screenshot:
   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much, my mistake was choosing REMK as the join field and PORT_ID as the target field. As you did in your screenshot on 3rd method, it works! I appreciate your fast reply a lot! Best.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked, so that others with similar questions will know it did.